# Security for collections with sensitive data

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I need security for some collections in the database. Because they contain some sensitive data, what approach should I adopt?

The problem is if I encrypt those fields then I am not able to manipulate them like aggregating the results or searching etc. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample document (Without any sensitive information).

You could have some queryable metadata such as lastModifiedDate or a category string about the collections in plain text.

Comment: Thanks dyouberg for reply let me show my example document. Here values array each value is encrypted.
{
  "memberId": ObjectId
  (
  "57720ce84d10573008ebd7a8"
  ),
  "values": [
    {
      "unitId": "57a08069531f45d3d6ea2790",
      "unitTypeId": "5770f8a5985c26381fa55ad5",
      "value": 0.0068039553660528
    },
    {
      "unitId": ObjectId
      (
      "57a08016531f45d3d6ea2783"
      ),
      "value": 0.00015,
      "unitTypeId": ObjectId
      (
      "5770f8a5985c26381fa55ad5"
      )
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You could try storing the encrypted data in a separate collection with a reference to the memberId.  Or you could use $unwind in an aggregation to perform groupings based off of the unitId and unitTypeId fields.  Is there a reason why the id's are not object ids in the first array?

Comment: Queryable Encryption Has just been announced and preview-released



Queryable Encryption is a feature that enables you to encrypt data in your application before you send it over the network to MongoDB while still maintaining the ability to query the encrypted data. With Queryable Encryption enabled, no MongoDB-managed service has access to your data in an unencrypted form.


https://www.wired.com/story/mongodb-queryable-encryption-databases &

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-releases-queryable-encryption-preview but I don’t know if it’s a legit answer yet.